# Pushing UIVIewController to UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface, uiview

I have a UIButton in UIVIewController and I need to push it to the UIVIew when I press the button.But this gives me the warning of `incompatible pointer type sending`

how to do this
What I am doing this:

```
-(void)press{
    displayView *disp=[[displayView alloc]init];
    [self presentModalViewController:disp animated:No];
}
```

this gives me warning and crashes my application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

presentModalViewController accepts a UIViewController instance (not UIView). If you want to display a particular view, place it within a view controller first.

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
DisplayView *displayView = [[DisplayView alloc] init];
[viewController.view addSubview: displayView];
[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:NO];
```